# Hyperledger fabric network on multiple machines/nodes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ethereum, ibm-blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-ca

We are facing issues to deploy our network on multiple machines. We want to deploy our network on local machines and wants the communications between different peers and organizations. So it is possible to use SOLO for communications. If yes then how. and If no then why?

We want to make small networks on 2 to 3 machines and then wants to combine all the small networks to build a giant network. how this will be possible. Looking for help.

Comment: Hi, while you are mentioning about `combine all the small networks`, did you mean those networks have different ledgers (they are in different Fabric channels) ?

Comment: yes they will have an different ledger.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your needs. Assuming you have two different networks (channels, ledgers) **network0** and **network1**; And two peers **peer0** (joined network0) and **peer1** (joined network1), do you try to access network1 from peer0 ?

Comment: yes you are right. thats what I have to do.

Comment: If so, I believe what you need is to ask peer0 to join network1 (and peer0 can share ledger1 with peer1). Then both peer0 and peer1 will receive the broadcast from the orderer when a new block of ledger1 is being added.

Comment: I am looking for solution. How gonna it will done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've understood your question, is how to connect multiple different networks to one "larger" network.

So, I think this statement is a misconception, correct me if I'm wrong but every hyperledger fabric network is created initially from one organization, which supposedly is the network initiator (a.k.a. network admin). Moreover, upon the creation of the network, the administrative figure that defines the network is the ordering service which is bonded to the initial organization. However, the initial state of the network changes as new members enter the network. The thing is that the new members who are entering the network do not have nor belong to another network. They enter the network created by the initial organization.

You might find the following documentation helpful:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/network/network.html
I hope this helped you with your confusion.

Finally, you can get started and build a network if you follow this:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/build_network.html